# Storing a monero address in smart contracts?

Tags: contract-development, contract-design, string

Assuming I would have to store Monero addresses or any [cryptonote](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CryptoNote) based coins addresses in a smart contract, would there be any issues?

Consider that those addresses are as long as this random monero address:

> 43ZmqBKrvcL7nRYfTTrpngJ8M9bB6HyuvVnQzqJJW5Gai1ScVVDeSy5jDkKtt7qgB1Ld4Fx3MHEw1HkwZNPVkpmN7rhk9YT

The following smart contract stores the above address, however are there any drawbacks such as potential cybersecurity issues? Also could that smart contract be improved to be more efficient by storing the monero address as bytes rather than string??

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.1;


contract Addresses
{

string public moneroAddress;

function setAddress(string address_)public returns(bool)
{ 
moneroAddress = address_;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The address you provided is 95 characters long. That means 190 bytes. That will not fit in any byte arrays Solidity supports. Your only options for storing it are either a `string` or `bytes` (dynamically-sized arrays, see https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.5.3/types.html#arrays for more details). But there are no efficiency improvements between those two options - they are essentially the same thing.

Your contract stores the address as it is - no extra padding of characters or anything like that. There are no security problems with storing it like that. Except of course if you'd like to keep the address secret as everything is public in Ethereum.